# In python mark the highest value as one, lowest as zero and everything else proportionally inbetween

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I have a list, I find the highest and lowest values in the list and I can normalize the highest value to 1 and reduce every other value accordingly.

I now want set the lowest value in the list to zero and every value to the position between zero and one that it should occupy. I do not know how to do this so any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
lst = [10, 20, 30, 40, 70, 90, 100]
adjusted_lst = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.7, 0.9, 1.0] #I can get to here but further I cannot. 
final_lst = [0.0, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, 1.0]
```

Comment: Subtract the lowest from all elements, then normalize?

Comment: This process is known as [normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_(image_processing))

Answer (score 0):

It's rather trivial math operation:

```
from __future__ import division
lst = [10, 20, 30, 40, 70, 90, 100]
lower = min(lst)
upper = max(lst)
processed = [(x - lower)/(upper - lower) for x in lst]
# [0.0, 0.1111111111111111, 0.2222222222222222, 0.3333333333333333,
#  0.6666666666666666, 0.8888888888888888, 1.0]
```

Comment: I'd shy away from importing `division` as it may have unforeseen consequences on the other code within the file.

Comment: What part of this code requires from __future__ import division? Sorry for noob questions.

Comment: @JamesLloyd int divided by int would yield int (rounded down) in Python 2. `from __future__ import division` changes default behaviour to Python 3 behaviour - division always returns float. To achieve same effect without `__future__` import you need to explicitly convert one of division argument to float - e.g. `float(x-lower)/(upper-lower)`.

Answer (score 0):

In order to normalize in any range whether `(0,1)` or `(0.5, 1.5)` or in general `(a, b)` the formula is:

```
X_new = ((X - X_min) / (X_max - X_min)) * (b - a) + a
```

where `(a, b)` is the normalized range.

Python code:

```
>>> X = [10, 20, 30, 40, 70, 90, 100]
>>> X_max = max(X)
>>> X_min = min(X)
>>> low_limit = 0.5  # 0 in your case
>>> up_limit = 1.5   # 1 in your case
>>> [((x - X_min)/(X_max - X_min)) * (up_limit - low_limit) + low_limit for x in map(float, X)]
[0.5, 0.6111111111111112, 0.7222222222222222, 0.8333333333333333, 1.1666666666666665, 1.3888888888888888, 1.5]
```